# Call to undefined function mysqli_query()

Tags: php

Can you help me trying to solve this problems? This code below is working in localhost, but somehow when i'm deploy this code to a hosting always appear pop up

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_query() in
>   /home/xxx/public_html/xxx/xxx_2/admin/function.php on line 660.

I'm already searching solution in internet, but none of them is working and  done check query and query is working though. Can you give me solution to solve this problems?

Below is code who me talking about ,

```
function connection (){
        $connection= new mysqli("localhost","root","","xxx_kms");
    return $connection;
}
function login($action,$timelog){
    $email=form_validation($_POST['email']);
    $password=form_validation($_POST['password']);
    $random_password=hash("sha256",$password);

        $sql="
        select ms_user.user_uid,ms_user.username,ms_user.email,ms_user.level,ms_user.division_uid,ms_division.division_uid
        from ms_user
        inner join ms_division on ms_user.division_uid=ms_division.division_uid
        where ms_user.email='".$email."' and ms_user.password='".$random_password."' and ms_user.status='0'";

        $ceksql=mysqli_query(connection(),$sql); <<--- Error appear in this line
        $result=mysqli_num_rows($ceksql);
            if($result==0){
            echo "<script>
                        alert('Username or Password is wrong');
                        window.location.href='login.php';
                </script>";
            }
            else {
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ceksql)){
                    $_SESSION['user_uid']=$row['user_uid'];
                    $_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
                    $_SESSION['division']=$row['division_uid'];
                    $_SESSION['level']=$row['level'];

                    $user_uid=$_SESSION['user_uid'];
                    $username=$_SESSION['username'];
                    $division=$_SESSION['division'];
                    $log="$username Login pada sistem";

                        if($row['level']==1){
                            sistem_log($log,$timelog,$user_uid,$division);  
                            header("location:index.php");               
                        }
                        if($row['level']==2){
                            sistem_log($log,$timelog,$user_uid,$division);  
                            header("location:../user/index.php");           
                        }

                }
            }

}
```

Comment: Is `mysqli` installed on your hosting?

Comment: miss match of Object oriented and non object oriented. Try the connection using `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");`.

Comment: i don't know about it , can you tell me to check "mysqli" is installed or not in hosting?

Comment: Check php.ini if you have mysqli extension enabled.

Comment: Frayne : I will try your suggestion , and give reports later~

Comment: @yosafatwahyusetyawan if it's one of the hosting services which have PHP pre-installed (i.e. you didn't install PHP yourself) then you probably need to ask their support team.

Comment: Aprokryfos : Thanks for your suggestion ,maybe i will ask to supporting team in that hosting.
Jan Holas : i will check in  php.ini as your suggestion

Comment: mysqli_query() is not in your server or not installed

Comment: Yup , i know it. That's make me sad . Then i should change all of my coding to mysql..

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that you use a Object oriented style for the connection and Procedural style for the Query in your project.

You can't Simultaneously use the functions like Object Oriented and NON-Object oriented. GO with one direction, either OOP or non-OOP.

Just change your connection like [Procedural style]:

```
function connection (){
    $connection= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","xxx_kms");
    return $connection;
}
```

Check it out the difference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php)

Comment: it's no use , the problems is not go away,  Still stuck in same problems  although i'm trying to use your method .

Comment: DID your `php.ini` file has the `extension=php_mysqli.dll` open?? if it is like `;extension=php_mysqli.dll` then remove the first `;` and save. then try again.

Comment: I don't know where location php.ini since this one using hosting not localhost. 
Can you tell me that location in CPanel ?

Comment: Search in  google `how to edit php.ini in cpanel`, you will be notified.